# Unexpected issue when encoding data using LabelEncoder and OneHotEncoder from sklearn

Tags: python, encoding, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am encoding some data to pass into an ML model using the LabelEncoder and OneHotEncoder from sklearn however I am getting an error back that relates to a column I that I don't think should be being encoded.

Here is my code;

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as py

Dataset = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\taylorr2\\Desktop\\SID Alerts.csv', sep = ',')
X = Dataset.iloc[:,:-1].values
Y = Dataset.iloc[:,18].values

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_X = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 0] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[:, 0])
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [0])
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
```

I can only see how I am trying to encode the first column of data however the error I am getting is the following;

```
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [0])
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-132-360fc0133165>", line 2, in <module>
    X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()

  File "C:\Users\taylorr2\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-    packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py", line 1902, in fit_transform
    self.categorical_features, copy=True)

  File "C:\Users\taylorr2\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py", line 1697, in _transform_selected
    X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csc', copy=copy, dtype=FLOAT_DTYPES)

  File "C:\Users\taylorr2\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 382, in check_array
    array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'A string that only appears in column 16 or 18 of my data'
```

What is it about my code that is making it think it needs to try and convert a value in column 16 or 18 into a float and anyway, what should be the issue with doing that!!?

Thanks in advance for your advice!

Comment: It doesnt matter where your string is. scikit-learn doesn't support string features. You must encode it as a number or dont supply that column.

Comment: That's exactly what this code is doing.

Comment: No, this code only labelencode your first column, and then  tries to apply onehotencoding on it. What about your column 16 or 18 which contains strings, as you yourself said.

Comment: This is my point. I thought I should be encoding the first column only (which is also a string) however this is giving me an error that relates to column 16! That shouldn't even be processed by this code as I understand it.

Comment: This is being processed because it is in your X. It doesnt matter where it is. Your X should be completely numerical

Comment: Ah ok. But what I am trying to do is turn all of the strings into numerical values.

Comment: Yes, I know. Thats what I suggested in first comment that you only supply column 0 to oneHotEncoder, and then can merge the result to your dataset.

Comment: Sorry I am not understanding what the issue is here still.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, this is actually a comment but due to my reputation I can't post comments yet :(

Probably that string appears on column 17 of your data, and I think it's because for some reason the last columns of the data are checked first (you can try passing less columns (e.g. 17 by passing X[:,0:17]) to see what happens. It'll complain about the last column again).

Anyway, the input to OneHotEncoder should be a matrix of integers, as described here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html.
But I think since you specified the index of the categorical features to OneHotEncoder class, that shouldn't matter anyway (at least I'd expect the non categorical features to be "ignored").

Reading the code in 'sklearn/preprocessing/data.py' I've seen that when they do "X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csc', copy=copy, dtype=FLOAT_DTYPES)", they are considering the non categorical features, even though their indexes are passed as argument to the function that calls check_array. I don't know, maybe it should be checked with the sklearn community on github?

Comment: Thanks for this response. I have been trying to get some help from GitHub but had no luck yet. Is there another way that I can achieve the same desired result?

Comment: I think it's like what Vivek Kumar suggested, you could supply only the first column to OneHotEncoder, something like:   

`temp = X[:,0] ; 
  temp = onehotencoder.fit_transform(temp.reshape(-1,1)).toarray();
  X = np.c_[temp,X[:,1:]]`

Comment: Oh and I only did temp.reshape(-1,1) because we're passing only one feature to OneHotEncoder, and on version 0.18 of sklearn it raises a warning if you don't do that

Comment: I don't want to only encode the first row though. I would like to do all categories.

Comment: Well since OneHotEncoder only accepts integers, you'll have to pass the entire X to LabelEncoder and then apply  OneHotEncoder

Answer (score 0):

@Taylrl,

I encountered the same behavior and found it frustrating. As @Vivek pointed out, Scikit-Learn requires *all* data to be numerical before it even considers selecting the columns provided in the `categorical_features` parameter.

Specifically, the column selection is handled by the `_transform_selected()` method in /sklearn/preprocessing/data.py and the very first line of that method is

`X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csc', copy=copy, dtype=FLOAT_DTYPES)`.

This check fails if *any* of the data in the provided dataframe `X` cannot be successfully converted to a float.

I agree that the documentation of sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder is very misleading in that regard.